# persist the state of 'Like' counter using redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to react, and I am trying to learn react and redux by myself.
I have a like counter into my application. The intended behavior is to persist the number of likes after refreshing the page. I did implement the code and it works; however, when refreshing the page the counter resets to zero. I tried to create an action for patch request, but always gives me `×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined`. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

my schema for one item looks like that looks like that, where likes is an attribute of the item.

```html
{
id: 1,
title: "A new cake recipe",
body: "Made of chocolate",
likes: 0,
created_at: "2018-07-06T14:48:23.377Z",
updated_at: "2018-07-06T14:49:59.582Z"
}
```

This is my Likes component

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Likes extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);
        this.state = {
            likes: 0,
            updated: false
        }
        this.updateLikes = this.updateLikes.bind(this);
    }

    updateLikes() {
        this.setState((prevState) => {

            return {
                likes: prevState.likes + 1,
                updated: true
                }
            })
            
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <button 
                    className="btn btn-success" 
                    onClick={this.updateLikes}>
                    Like <strong>{this.state.likes}</strong>
                </button> 
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        likes: state.likes
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Likes)
```

this is my reducer

```js
const initialState ={
    likes: 0
}
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    console.log(action.type)
    switch(action.type){
        case 'INC_LIKES':
            return {likes: state.likes + 1}
        default:
            return state;
    }
        
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into something like [redux-localstorage](https://github.com/elgerlambert/redux-localstorage) for persisting your state?

Comment: yes I did. there is a ‘redux-persist’ library but I coudn't implement it into my app, I will put mine here too

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use localStorage middleware for redux:

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-storage
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-localstorage-simple

Local storage is html 5 standard approach of preserving application state on the client side:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: my app is like that const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(reducers, /* preloadedState, */ composeEnhancers(
        applyMiddleware(promise)
    )); I tried to add redux-localstorage-simple between other braces after promise, like that:const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(reducers, /* preloadedState, */ composeEnhancers(
        applyMiddleware(promise)(save)
    )); . Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

[`window.localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) can be manually leveraged to persist `state` between page loads.

Otherwise, a middleware library such as [`redux-localstorage`](https://github.com/elgerlambert/redux-localstorage) might be suitable.

Implementation of the former would probably be similar to the following:

***Action***

```
const updateLikes = (likes = 0) => {
  localStorage.setItem('likes', likes)
  return {type: 'INC_LIKES', payload: likes}
}
```

***Reducer***

```
const reducer = (state = {likes: parseInt(localStorage.getItem('likes') || 0)}, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'INC_LIKES':
      return {likes: action.payload}
    default:
      return state
  }       
}
```

***Connection***

```
connect(mapStateToProps, {updateLikes})
```

***Usage***

```
this.props.updateLikes(this.props.likes + 1)
```